Why did my answer get removed? (4 upvotes, 3 downvotes, and OP said the answer was useful)
I answered What strategies are effective at curtailing overly aggressive deleting of compliant questions and answers? as follows:

Allow users to cast a "don't delete" vote before the post is deleted.

It got removed by a mod who left this comment:

This is not an effective strategy - deleting here. Rory Alsop

However, the answer got 4 upvotes and 3 downvotes, and OP said the answer was useful. Since the answer was deemed useful by at least 4 users, including the OP, why remove it?

The answer with vote count:

OP feedback about the answer:


It is not an effective strategy. It is not even a strategy. You cannot do this. In fact you already had comments on that post pointing this out.
It is not of value on this meta, and in fact if you want to bring about a change that significant to how SE works, go and ask it on main meta as a feature request.
Until that happens and it is implemented, it is not something that exists.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
